# Using a array variable in a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am having an issue trying to work out how to use a function variable in a foreach loop so that I can do the following but its not working.

**$var =**

```
array(7) { [0]=> array(3) { ["listingId"]=> int(532712629) } [1]=> array(3) { ["listingId"]=> int(532712202) }
```

**Works but not right:**

```
foreach($var as $varr)
{
  var_dump($varr['id']);
{
```

**Goal** - Having the array variable as the foreach value

```
    foreach($var['id'] as $item)
    {
       if($item === $foo)
      {
      }
   }
```

Comment: what's your question exactly?

Comment: What does your $var array look like? What you're trying to do right now looks like you're parsing a multidimensional array. If you can show us what $var looks like and what you get when you do `var_dump($varr['id']);` then we will get a better sense of what to do.

Comment: assuming `$varr` is your array, then your foreach is backwards. syntax is `foreach($array as $key => $value)`.

Comment: @Stegrex I have updated my question with the array

Comment: @BrianGlaz How can I achieve my goal

Comment: @MarcB no its not I want a foreach based on ID

Comment: I think you should post your full `$var` instead of just chunks of it. As of now, it shows that you have the parent array with 7 elements, but I only see 2. And each child array has 3 elements but you only posted `["listing_id"] => int ...`

Comment: You have a multidimensionall array, you propably need another `foreach` loop in your loop!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will loop through the array  in your $var array:

```
foreach ($var as $k=> $v){
   foreach ($v as $k2=> $v2){
      echo $k2." ".$v2;
   }
}
```

in the for each, the $k will retunr the array key (numeric OR textual) as $v will return the value.
You can output an array's content by using `print_r($array);` in most case.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
foreach($var[0] as $varr)
{
  echo $varr->listingid;
}
```

Comment: From your code `$varr` would be an integer, not an object

Comment: what if property `listingid` does not exists? what if `$var` is not an object?